# Firebase saving to database from cloud function API

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have wrote a Firebase cloud function that can be accessed via a REST API. The code is given below.

What I need to do is, when the user submits some values from the front end via the 'Web service URL' .

1.) I need these data to be saved in the Firebase-realtime database.

2.) I refereed to several tutorials on the net, and didn't understand what     `var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");` does in the following code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./My-Service.json");
// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://my-xx0xx.firebaseio.com/"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");


exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req, res, () => {
        var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  },
  gracehop: {
    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
  }
});

        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Not allowed'
        });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        message: req.body
    });
      });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does write data into the database, under the `server` node (location). The result in the database is as follows (export from the Firebase console):

```
  "server" : {
    "saving-data" : {
      "fireblog" : {
        "users" : {
          "alanisawesome" : {
            "date_of_birth" : "June 23, 1912",
            "full_name" : "Alan Turing"
          },
          "gracehop" : {
            "date_of_birth" : "December 9, 1906",
            "full_name" : "Grace Hopper"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So, basically, answer to Question #1 is: "It is saved".

Question #2: The value `db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog")` is an instance of a `Reference` which "represents a specific location in your Database and can be used for reading or writing data to that Database location", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

`var usersRef = ref.child("users");` is also a Reference, that you obtain via the `child()` method, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child

So, by combining the initial Reference and the `child()` method, when you do `usersRef.set({})` you write to the following path: `server/saving-data/fireblog/users`. Which is what is reflected above in the export of the database.

Note that with your current code, you will **always** write the same data at the location, i.e. the following object:

```
{
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  },
  gracehop: {
    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
  }
}
```

Again, this is reflected above in the export of the database.

With such a Cloud Function, that you call through HTTPS, you would classically get the data you want to write to the database in the body of the HTTP request.

---

Last point: I would re-organise your function as follows:

```
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db1.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const usersRef = ref.child("users");

        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Not allowed'
            })
        } else {
            return usersRef.set({
                alanisawesome: {
                    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
                    full_name: "Alan Turing"
                },
                gracehop: {
                    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
                    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
                }
            }).then(() => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: req.body
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                return res.status(500).send(error);
            })
        }

    })

});
```

Finally, I  would suggest you look at thee following video from teh Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

Comment: I get this error ` error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return`.

Comment: There was a closing parenthesis missing in my initial code (I've corrected in my answer) but the Cloud Function works correctly, I've tried it. The database is updated, when calling https://us-central1-yourprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile with a POST HTTP request

Comment: But I still still this error `37:19  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return`. when I remove the `return ` from `return usersRef.set({...` and replace `return res.status(200).json({` then it works. But, I don't see the response from my React code.

Comment: Where do you see this error and where is used the React code?

Comment: Yes from the React end.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. This code is a Cloud Function code that is supposed to be stored in Google's cloud (Firebase) and runs in a managed environment on their servers.See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't return this `res.status(200).json({
                    message: req.body
                });` . Also, I get the error `  37:21  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return` when trying to deploy the code to firebase via the command `firebase deploy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170602/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-illep).